# CUDA: Getting linking error only in device emulation mode

Tags: visual-studio, dll, compiler-construction, linker, cuda

I am compiling a dll which goes just fine unless I use the -deviceemu mode.

In this case I get several of the following linking errors:

> > CUDAKernel_ColourHist.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> >     ___cudaMutexOperation@4 referenced in function ___uAtomicAdd
> >     1>CUDAKernel_1.obj : error LNK2001:
> >     unresolved external symbol
> >     ___cudaMutexOperation@4 1>CUDAKernel_2.obj : error LNK2001:
> >     unresolved external symbol
> >     ___cudaMutexOperation@4

Which led me to believe perhaps I wasn't linking the correct files, but I believe I am.  I am using Visual Studio and any help woud be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I was using an older version of the libraries, linking with the newer libraries fixed the problem.